# Set the minimum number of instances

Tags: google-app-engine

I understand that App Engine handles scaling automatically. However, in order to test drive some multi-instance / consolidated state scenarios, I'd like to instruct App Engine to fire up a minimum of 5 instances, even if load does not justify this.

Is there a way of doing this via app.yaml or Dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the Min Pending Latency to a very low number (e.g. 100ms), and then send a burst of requests to your app. Then the scheduler will start spinning up multiple instances to handle these requests.

You may need to use a tool for automated load testing - it will be difficult to achieve this manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `min_idle_instances` value controls.

In app.yaml:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 5
```

Comment: Not exactly. Idle instances are used only to handle the **increase** in traffic, i.e. they would be only used when new dynamic instances are spun up. In steady traffic, idle instances would handle no load.

Comment: So does this mean, I cannot force App Engine to run more than a single instance even if load is almost idle? I have to run load tests to force it to get under stress?

Comment: You can force the instances to be running, but you can't force them to service requests.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use either `automatic_scaling` or `manual_scaling`. With automatic scaling, you can only influence how many instances are started, with manual scaling, you can decide how many instances you wish to use. Place the following in your `app.yaml`, or module yaml file:

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 5
```